# -webkit-transform rotate with js variable for degree value

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to use variable MyDiv1 in place of "25" below, and can't seem to find the right syntax.  Everything else works fine, I am just stuck on how to combine MyDiv1 with deg in the "(25deg)" part.

```
var degrees = (ata * (180/Math.PI));

$("#demo").html(degrees);

var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;

var element = document.getElementById('flim');

element.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(25deg)";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
element.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + MyDiv1 + "deg)";
```

Comment: Didn't even have time to edit my question for clarity before you replied with the right answer.  Thank you.

Comment: That's what we're here for :) If you're satisfied please upvote (if possible) and mark it as the answer.